# Show the PDF but not to Download

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome, pdf

I have many PDF links, When I click any one of them it will be open in a new tab and there are many options in PDF reader.

[image]

Basically I want to `disable` the download button only.

Or let me explain it more,
Basically a client will upload their policy in PDF but that should be show in normal view such as Image or convert into text not in PDF.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505505/hide-disable-download-button-on-chrome-pdf-viewer

Comment: It seems to be a feature of google-chrome, and you just cannot it alter your users' client settings.

Comment: The short answer is "you can't". Anything that is put online can be downloaded. (because in order to show X to the user, the browser has to download X first, so it's already on the user's hard drive anyway, and could be grabbed from there)

Comment: So this is indeed an xy problem. You should always ask about your actual problem, not your attempted solution. Unless the client absolutely insists on uploading a PDF, use TinyMCE or the like. They post their policy in there, and you can grab it and display it.

Answer (score 1):

```
use #toolbar=0&navpanes=0
```

```html
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_tutorial.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Output :

http://prntscr.com/i4bxhg

it will work.
you can get the complete list from here,
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf

Comment: Worth mentioning here is the fact that this is sending your PDF to an external service (Google Documents) and that your document has to have public access for this to work.

Comment: @Nimesh Patel - This solution is fine, but it is only working in google chrome.
What about firefox, and Edge etc?