# how to forbidden user download pdf or other files at django

Tags: django

When I use the below code in my django views, it will show download icon at Chrome. Is there any method to forbidden user download my pdf for privacy restrictions.

```
def home(request):
    data = open("/path/mypdf.pdf", 'rb').read()
    return HttpResponse(image_data, content_type="application/pdf")
```

[Chrome screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rPuo.jpg)

Comment: The only way to prevent download is to not send it to the user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide/Disable download button on Chrome PDF Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505505/hide-disable-download-button-on-chrome-pdf-viewer)